# Unable to set timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I am unable to set timezone for my DateTime objects.
Here is my code :

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',time(),new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
print_r($dt->getTimeZone());
```

Here is the output :

```
DateTimeZone Object
(
)
```

I also tried putting these lines at the top (one at a time) - without any success:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Calcutta');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Kolkata');
```

Comment: What does `$dt->getTimeZone()->getName()` print?

Comment: You can't get more info from `print_r` about the date/time classes. So, your code probably works, you just don't check it correctly.

Comment: @Gordon  - yes it exists in the output of print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(16));

Comment: @dharm0us: `U` is the UNIX timestamp, it is an absolute time which does not require timezone. I think you can omit the timezone and still get correct results.

Comment: @SalmanA no. He will get a DateTime object on UTC timezone

Comment: @SalmanA - I wanted to get the same output as I get from date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timestamp) with DateTime class. date() function picks up the timezone which I set using date_default_timezone_set(), but DateTime doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you specified UNIX timestamp in the parameter. See what [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) says.

> **The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the time parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp** (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

What you are trying to do can be easily done by,

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
```

If you have a variable that contains UNIX timestamp, first create a DateTime object with it. Then set the new TimeZone.

```
$dt = new DateTime("@$timestamp");
$dt->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/topBCR

Comment: but I don't want to use the Current Timestamp always.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$dateTimeZoneAsia = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
$dateTimeAsia = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZoneAsia);
$timeOffset = $dateTimeZoneAsia->getOffset($dateTimeAsia);
var_dump($timeOffset);
?>
```